# laravel one to many relationship , not showing data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

i have two classes named academy and pitch 
the pitch can have many academies and the acdemy belongs to one pitch
in my show view of the academy i can see the pitch name using this

```
{{$academy->pitch->name}}
```

but in reverse it sont work , i mean i want to list names of acadmies in each pitch

my models

academy model

```
public function pitch(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Pitch::class ,'pitch_id');
    }
```

pitch model

```
public function academies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Academy::class);
    }
```

i tried this but it dont work

```
 @foreach ($pitch->academies as $academy)
                        <li></li>
                    @endforeach
```

the error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'academies.pitch_pitch_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `academies` where `academies`.`pitch_pitch_id` = 5 and `academies`.`pitch_pitch_id` is not null)
```

Comment: you need to specify the foreign and primary key in both the relations if they are not strict to laravel default primary-foreign key tempalte

Comment: it worked  but it only shows the first one

Comment: ` @foreach ($pitch->academies as $academy)
                    {{$academy->name}}
  @endforeach`

Comment: it shows only the first one

Comment: check the order of the parameters

Comment: they're correct

Comment: can you please post them?

Comment: ` public function pitch(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Pitch::class ,'pitch_id');
    }`                                                                                                                              
 ` public function academies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Academy::class, 'academy_id');
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function academies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Academy::class, 'academy_id');
    }

 public function pitch(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Pitch::class ,'pitch_id');
    }
```

in my view

```
@foreach ($pitch->academies as $academy)

                    {{$academy->name}}
                    @endforeach
```

i works now

Comment: are you sure that is not that this pitch has only one academy?